# Launch "safe" Firefox

Tags: firefox, continuous-integration

I'm trying to run jasmine unit tests on a CI server. To do that I have to launch a browser (FF in my case.)

I have a vnc server running on the server, so the browser has a display to attach to. However, when the browser is killed or terminated ungracefully (which can happen if a build fails), If I simply run "/usr/bin/firefox", I get a pop-up message from Firefox, and obviously the tests won't work.

Is there a set of flag I can use to always launch FF (as if it was a regular startup ?)

Note that :

- `/usr/bin/firefox -safe` would not work, as it opens a popup to warn about safe mode
- `/usr/bin/firefox -P xyz` would not work, as it opens a popup to define the profile

Thanks

Comment: If you mean the session-restore feature; `about:config` & disable `browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash`

Comment: This can happen, but there are other situations where the browser just will not open...